Duplicae images
I have a problem with duplicate images when ever I create POST request for the same product. I tried to change store configuration for Media Gallery, but failed to resolve the problem. Magento version I am using is: Magento ver. 2.4.7-p2.
Post a product with one image using BASE64 format option on BULK API endpoint.
Go to the product in the admin.
See that 1 image is imported.
Post the same request again
See that the same image is added twice: for the original "types": ["image]" and for duplicate: "types": [].
Thanks in advance,
Stevan
